# IONIC android FCM notification

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Firebase notification I got notification when application is background but when I Open application without tap of notification, data not reflect in IONIC android application.

when application is foreground then data reflect automatically.

I have used cordova-plugin-messaging plugin also but not work.

I Have used

FCMPlugin.onNotification(
            function(data){

```
          if(data.wasTapped){
            console.log(data);

          }else{
            console.log(data);

          }

        },
        function(msg){
          console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
        },
        function(err){
          console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
        }
      );
```

and also used:

window.cordova.plugins.firebase.messaging.onMessage(function(data) {

```
      console.log(data);

});
```

but it works on when app is foreground and when we clicked on notification..

I want to retrieve data when app is background and without click on notification when app open.

Thanks for answer

Comment: Hi. Do post relevant code snippets.

Comment: FCMPlugin.onNotification(
            function(data){

            
              if(data.wasTapped){
                console.log(data);
                
              }else{
                console.log(data);
               
              }
               
            },
            function(msg){
              console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
            },
            function(err){
              console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
            }
          );

Comment: If the user receives a notification when your app is killed/not running, if the app is opened without clicking the notification, then the data will not be sent to the app. That is normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`sendPushPayload( data );`

```
Intent NotificationIntent = new Intent(this, FCMPluginActivity.class)
 .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)

  .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  for (String key : data.keySet()) {
  NotificationIntent.putExtra(key, data.get(key).toString());
  }
  startActivity(NotificationIntent);
```

put above code in your android native file `(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java )` and cordova plugin android `(src ->android-> MyFirebaseMessagingService.java)` file, if make above changes means , app is in background you push the notification mean app will automatically get open.